# Is there a convenient small Unix virtual machine I can install as an Android app?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, android

Ubuntu for Android seems to be missing in action.

I'm travelling tomorrow and I need to take a basic Linux machine with me. I'd rather just take my tablet than a laptop. So is there a reasonable simple Linux virtual machine that I can install as an Android app. and which I can ssh into with Putty from any PC I find (ideally via the USB cable)?

I'd like to be able to run at least emacs, git and rsync. And ideally Python.

Comment: With the limited amount of memory on your tablet/phone this seems a little counter productive to me.

Comment: If you're specifically looking for a Linux VM, you might consider amending the question title. If you're not, you might consider amending the question text.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is one VM called Linux-on-android. I have heard of it, few of my friends used it and they had good experience. You can find it on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxonandroid/).

Comment: Can you be more specific about where on sourceforge it can be found? That's a big site.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxonandroid/

Comment: Otherwise Try this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of hoping to avoid having to root the device. I just want a simple unix environment with the tools I need. Not to have full unix control over the android device itself. (Not even looking for vnc or a gui desktop)

Comment: Thank you, this looks very nice :D I will try it right away! Has anyone tried to install Arch with this? By the way I have SE Live With Walkman, is this phone capable of running Linux that way? It has very limited resources..

Comment: @Alko As a personal opinion Its not good idea to run it on SE Live

Comment: @Aryan I think so too...but what the hell :P

Answer (score 2):

Read this how-to: [Debian & Android Together on G1](http://www.saurik.com/id/10)

There is [arm debian](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiHowto), you can easy setup it on your android device, at least, you need root and 420Mb of free disk space (minimal lenny setup size).

In the second, there are many [Qemu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) ports, browse market. One of it - [Limbo is a PC Emulator (x86)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.max2idea.android.limbo.main). In this way you need no root, but you lose the speed.

Answer (score 1):

There's "debian noroot".  May or may not work for you, it's a 200 MB download.

I just have it for SSH and to impress my friends.

Answer (score 1):

On a rooted android phone you can install [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy&hl=en_GB). It is based on chroot and allows ssh and vnc to the VM.

Also, [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) is a terminal emulator which runs a small Linux VM, which supports apt to install packages. This works without a rooted android phone.

Answer (score 1):

These days I'm very happy with UserLand : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula

It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent Andronix app which allows running modified distributions without having to root the phone. However, there are many restrictions https://docs.andronix.app/get-started/limitations/ some of which may interfere with the intended usage scenario